# How can I fix Haskell version conflicts with dependencies?

Tags: haskell

I have tried the command "cabal install HaskellAnalysisProgram" to install the Haskell package "HaskellAnalysisProgram" on my Macbook Pro of operating system macOS Big Sur version 11.2.3 with Apple M1 chip. However, a frustrating error relating to dependency conflicts appear when I tried to install it. I also heard that some other Mac users can install "HaskellAnalysisProgram" or any other Haskell packages depending on older version(s) of other Haskell packages without any issue. My cabal configuration is still at its default. May I know how to fix this issue.

Notes: the image of the error is attached

[HaskellAnalysisProgram Installation Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDJce.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

HaskellAnalysisProgram depends on haskell-src-exts 1.20.*, which in turn depends on base < 4.13. Thus, if you want to use HaskellAnalysisProgram without modifications, you need to downgrade to GHC 8.6.5, the last version of Haskell to include such an old version of base.

Comment: Currently I am using GHC version 8.10.4. If I type in the command "ghcup install ghc", it automatically installs GHC version 8.10.4 on my Mac. So, how to downgrade my GHC version to 8.6.5? This is because if I install GHC version 8.6.5 now, my Mac will detect the latest GHC version and use it to install Haskell packages.

Comment: Nevermind. Thanks. I've tried it and it works.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept it with the check mark.

Comment: @DominicTjiptono With `ghcup`, the way to go is `ghcup list --tool ghc` to see what versions are available, then `ghcup install ghc <version>`. I learned this by poking around in `ghcup --help`.